HSQLDB mvlocks concurrency model blocks reads when used with Hibernate
When using a HSQLDB with Hibernate and Spring, I run into a concurrency issue. I have two threads accessing the same table. One thread has a long running read write transaction, the other thread frequently access the table read only, but with just a short transaction. The main issue is that the long running transaction was blocking the quicker ones.
When check the documentation of HSQLDB I found the different concurreny models. It seemed the MVLOCKS or MVCC should help me in this situation.
With MVLOCKS the issue seems to be still prevalent, while with MVCC it actually works. My assumption would be that with MVLOCKS it should work too, and I want to understand why in this case it does not?
I prepared an example application that shows the problem https://github.com/fridewald/hsqldb-test
It uses plain hibernate sessions as I was not able to reproduce the issues otherwise.
Here you see how I changed the settings to mvlocks or mvcc in the application.properties file
# this does not work, it blocks the reads. Why?
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:hsqldb:mem:testdb;hsqldb.tx=mvlocks
# this works
#spring.datasource.url=jdbc:hsqldb:mem:testdb;hsqldb.tx=mvcc

Here you see the part that has a long running transaction
@Component
@Service
public class SlowUpdates {

    ...
    @Scheduled(fixedRate = 10000)
    public void slowlyUpdatingLamps() {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                log.info("try to slow update");
                try (

                        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();) {
                    session.beginTransaction();

                    long now = System.currentTimeMillis();

                    CriteriaBuilder lCriteriaBu = session.getCriteriaBuilder();
                    CriteriaQuery<Lamp> lQuery = lCriteriaBu.createQuery(Lamp.class);
                    Root<Lamp> lRoot = lQuery.from(Lamp.class);
                    lQuery.select(lRoot).where(lCriteriaBu.equal(lRoot.get("numberOfLamps"), 3));
                    log.info("Lamp read with findById(1L):");
                    List<Lamp> lamps = session.createQuery(lQuery).getResultList();

                    for (Lamp l : lamps) {
                        l.setLastUpdated(now);
                        session.persist(l);
                        log.info(l.toString());
                    }
                    session.flush();
                    // Wait 5 seconds and keep transaction open
                    Thread.sleep(5000);
                    List<Lamp> lamps2 = session.createQuery(lQuery).getResultList();
                    for (Lamp l : lamps2) {
                        l.setLastUpdated(now);
                        session.persist(l);
                        log.info(l.toString());
                    }
                    session.getTransaction().commit();
                    log.info("Session end");
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    log.error("Error in slowlyUpdatingLamps", e);
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }
}

here the part that tries to read from the table
public class FastReads {

    ...

    @Scheduled(fixedRate = 500)
    public void readLamps() {
        log.info("try to fast read");
        try (
                Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();) {
            session.beginTransaction();
            session.setDefaultReadOnly(true);
            log.info("Lamp read with findById(1L):");
            Lamp lamp = session.get(Lamp.class, 1L);
            log.info(lamp.toString());
            session.getTransaction().commit();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Error in readLamps", e);
        }
    }
}

I already tried to set session.setDefaultReadOnly(true); for the reading transaction, but this did not have any effect. Is there another way to tell hibernate that the transaction or session is read only that will be correctly forwarded to hsqldb?
When trying a similar example with two sql consoles on a hsqldb database, mvlocks was behaving as expected.

Hibernate's read-only mode does not affect database transactions. This is an internal optimization at the Hibernate level that allows you to avoid wasting resources on tracking changes in objects loaded from the database. Transactions are best made as short as possible. If you need to process a large amount of data, it makes sense to make many short transactions than one long one.

Thanks for the answer. Do you know if it's possible to manually set the transaction mode in my application?

@d2quadra You can change the transaction isolation level using the isolation parameter in the @Transactional annotation. You can also use EntityManager.find() to find an entity with locking, EntityManager.lock() to explicitly lock an already loaded entity, TypedQuery.setLockMode() and Query.setLockMode() to lock when executing JPQL, Criteria API or Native Query queries, EntityManager.refresh() to update an entity from the database with locking.
